# update_post_meta from data in multidimensional array created from a form

Tags: array, post-meta

So, I have a few form fields like so:

```
<input name='mainStageSatOrder[theband][theid]' type='hidden' class='band-id' value='' />";
<input name='mainStageSatOrder[theband][theorder]' type='hidden' class='band-order' value='' />";
```

As you can see, these form fields (of which there are more, these are just examples of both types) create a multi-dimensional array like so (I hope, please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
Array (
[mainStageSatOrder] => Array
    (
        [theband] => Array
            (
                [theid] => 1
                [theorder] => 5
            )

        [theband] => Array
            (
                [theid] => 2
                [theorder] => 8
            )
    )
)
```

I want these values to use the update_post_meta function to update the relevant fields when the page update is submitted. I know I can hook into the submit action post_submitbox_start action which I understand just fine.

What I'm not sure on, is what the PHP might be once the submit button is clicked. What I want to happen is that when the submit button is clicked, the multidimensional array is looped through using a foreach loop and for each 'theband' sub-array, the two values are used in the update_post_meta function.

```
foreach(???) {
    update_post_meta( 1, 'theorder', '5' ); //where 1 and 5 are values passed from the MD array
}
```

So, the process goes:

1) User clicks publish/update button
2) All values from all fields are passed into the multidimensional array
3) The MD array is looped through and, using update_post_meta, the relavent data is updated
4) Confirm yes/no

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First off, there's a problem with your array. Arrays can not have duplicate keys. So, only the first key will be saved. You need to change your form to something like this.

```
<input name='mainStageSatOrder[theband0][theid]' type='hidden' class='band-id' value='' />";
<input name='mainStageSatOrder[theband0][theorder]' type='hidden' class='band-order' value='' />";
<input name='mainStageSatOrder[theband1][theid]' type='hidden' class='band-id' value='' />";
<input name='mainStageSatOrder[theband1][theorder]' type='hidden' class='band-order' value='' />";
```

The array will look like this

```
$array = array(
    'mainStageSatOrder' => array(
        'theband0' => array(
            'theid' => 1,
            'theorder' => 5
        ),
        'theband1' => array(
            'theid' => 2,
            'theorder' => 8
        )
    )
);
```

You don't need a foreach loop while saving the meta data. You can instead save it as an array. WordPress will automatically serialize it for you.

```
$array = $_POST['mainStageSatOrder'];
update_post_meta( $postid, 'mainStageSatOrder', $array );
```

And, while retriving the values..

```
$data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mainStageSatOrder', true);
```

The returned `$data` will be an array.

Comment: Does anyone know why this isn't the accepted answer?  I just read through this and applied a part of it and it did exactly what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

You got a litte thinking problem with your MD array, it should look like that, otherwise you will overwrite data within your form:

```
["mainStageSatOrder"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> array(1) {
        ["theband"]=> array(2) {
            ["theid"]=> int(1)
            ["theorder"]=> int(5)
        }
    }
    [1]=> array(1) {
        ["theband"]=> array(2) {
            ["theid"]=> int(2)
            ["theorder"]=> int(8)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you got two options (I'd recommend option B, because you might not need the single meta data without the context)

**Option A:** Save your data in single meta fields. You will need the parent_key (`$key` or `'mainStageSatOrder'`), `$row_id` and field_id (`$sub_key` or `$key`) to get your data.

```
function save($post_id) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) || !array_key_exists('mainStageSatOrder', $_POST) )
        return;
    foreach ($_POST['mainStageSatOrder'] as $row_id => $rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_value) {
                    $meta_key = '_'.$key.'_'.$row_id.'_'.$sub_key;
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $sub_value);
                }
            } else {
                $meta_key = "_mainStageSatOrder_".$row_id."_".$key;
                update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_mainStageSatOrder', array_keys($_POST['mainStageSatOrder']));
}
```

**Option B:** Save your data in a serialized array (WordPress handles the serialization). To access and do stuff with the array again, just `unserialize()` the meta_value.

```
function save_array($post_id) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) || !array_key_exists('mainStageSatOrder', $_POST) )
        return;
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_mainStageSatOrder', $_POST['mainStageSatOrder']);
}
```

Somewhere in your PHP code:

```
$mainStageSatOrder = unserialize(
    get_post_meta(
        get_the_ID(), 
        '_mainStageSatOrder', 
        true
    )
);
```

Comment: OK, thanks :) I'll give both a go and get back to you.