# Save / Update meta data as multidimensional array

Tags: posts, array, save-post

I need some help with saving my meta data from a post.
On the editpage I have the following input fields

```
<input type="text" name="data[color][]" value="red"/>
<input type="text" name="data[color][]" value="blue"/>
<input type="text" name="data[size][]" value="small"/>
<input type="text" name="data[width][]" value="30"/>
<input type="text" name="data[width][]" value="32"/>
```

If I click on save / update post the array is saved as

```
array(
    color => array("blue"),
    size => array("small"),
    width => array("32"),
);
```

It has to be saved as

```
array(
    color => array("red", "blue"),
    size => array("small"),
    width => array("30", "32"),
);
```

Wordpress get only the last items.

How can I fixed this?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220483/update-post-meta-from-data-in-multidimensional-array-created-from-a-form

Comment: Hi WebElaine this does not fix my issue :( I think the issue is in the serialize function from Wordpress. Is it possible to disable the serialize for these inputs?

Comment: No, postmeta arrays are always serialized. It might be worth looking into a simpler postmeta structure - i.e. save the color as one piece of postmeta, the size as another, the width as another.